# Filtering Based on Matching Values in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I've got a dataset in AWS Quicksight that looks like:

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 3 |
| c | 4 | 5 |

I want to make a vertical bar chart that displays value1, value2 per id but it should not display id in which value1==value2.

My intuition was:

1. Create a parameter, `MatchingValues`, with data type `integer`, multiple values, dynamic default with `user name column = id`, `default value column = value2`
2. Then a new filter for `value1`, Sum aggregation, filter condition as Does Not Equals, and used the `MatchingValues` parameter

The above filter on the bar chart seems to do nothing, I see bars for all three ids when the expectation would be removing the `b` bar as `value1 == value2`.

I think I'm just misunderstanding parameters and filters based on some of the stuff I've seen online. Is this type of filtering possible? I would think since I can easily write in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE value1 <=> value2
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a calculated field *myfilter*?

```
ifelse(value1 != value2, 1, 0)
```

Then add a filter to your bar chart where *myfilter* = 1. FYI this will also filter out rows if value1 and/or value2 is null.